# numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types

Tags: python, django, numpy

```
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U1580'), dtype('<U1580')) -> dtype('<U1580')
```

I am trying to perform the following operation:

```
dist = np.linalg.norm(encoding - db_enc)
```

where encoding is a 128 dimensional vector of a face sent via a POST request and db_enc is another 128 dimensional vector that I am fetching from Sqlite3 database. I am getting the above error on performing this step. Here is the encoding in detail,

```
print("ENC ", type(encoding), encoding, np.shape(encoding))

ENC  <class 'numpy.ndarray'> [[ 0.09602562  0.05026172  0.106613    0.11637867  0.13730541  0.18687613
   0.13980152 -0.10983124  0.01835017 -0.06333953 -0.06147085  0.0549635
   0.02799656  0.00092633  0.11221859 -0.05192785  0.0525886   0.07087591
  -0.10972961  0.01514653  0.01200427  0.05329731  0.04005743  0.18915842
   0.04145951 -0.20928082 -0.16869229 -0.06036214 -0.04235162  0.07824261
   0.07138225  0.1312568  -0.09781478  0.12874082  0.03722986 -0.01082433
   0.10047887  0.00800437 -0.04152641 -0.0306553   0.13605222  0.01289378
   0.05760223 -0.19195035 -0.12237714 -0.07873389  0.00380635  0.02028097
   0.02223298  0.06474376  0.10941633 -0.14064552  0.08936299  0.00388683
   0.07314923  0.04556359 -0.02430227  0.11343706  0.00779198 -0.00964779
  -0.08630823  0.12208205 -0.05156697 -0.3145251   0.10649662  0.09643669
   0.05130563 -0.07409885 -0.26777127  0.05541156 -0.00147743  0.11800249
  -0.01156744  0.06501945 -0.00601065  0.085051    0.07932617 -0.08163948
   0.04494501 -0.03012008  0.01525374  0.06678153  0.01800733 -0.0201263
   0.07194183 -0.03790623  0.00289917 -0.0186056  -0.13076556  0.10577566
   0.07499494 -0.11745209  0.09151422  0.00840714 -0.06819624  0.0245196
  -0.01500007 -0.00589196  0.05808676  0.09107708  0.07078542  0.00117582
  -0.04596691  0.12681791 -0.06487873 -0.00370738 -0.02379089 -0.0916268
  -0.07825013  0.06853001 -0.00962984  0.06818784  0.07526734 -0.0005998
  -0.01838216 -0.00074842 -0.08485842  0.10574327 -0.12667136  0.10527002
   0.0553649   0.0220931  -0.04728016  0.01509122  0.01982033  0.10371249
  -0.06818289 -0.1270394 ]] (1, 128)
```

and the corresponding database value

```
print("DB ", type(db_enc), db_enc, np.shape(db_enc))

DB  <class 'numpy.ndarray'> [[ 0.1616196  -0.06403983  0.00219853 -0.04197867  0.09346917  0.20562127
   0.12494124  0.02679994 -0.127634   -0.1126218  -0.03107646  0.04363777
   0.14626062  0.03845457  0.07879496 -0.11283173  0.01420811 -0.02750769
  -0.06326418  0.13397539  0.07688539  0.05936693  0.00945647  0.15419547
  -0.08248097 -0.07293285 -0.14824665 -0.15512463 -0.00425251  0.07445055
  -0.03990018  0.0395442  -0.14082795  0.0743586   0.02989104  0.02714477
   0.01490993  0.09542259 -0.03989129 -0.02652638  0.08977504  0.03180737
  -0.10132375 -0.07919461 -0.15734208  0.01482354  0.03443371  0.03917413
  -0.08184692  0.04209467 -0.03919723 -0.11930565  0.08438748  0.07760657
   0.08840926 -0.01585769 -0.01170482  0.17661    -0.04050164 -0.08612555
  -0.03465237  0.15780036  0.07520261 -0.17770033  0.02524511  0.02246985
   0.11478782  0.03914222 -0.09477007 -0.12463204  0.03759931  0.05503495
  -0.00029514 -0.00599168  0.01094351  0.09305067 -0.04536207 -0.10035587
   0.1543854   0.11397277  0.0400256   0.01436814 -0.01748643 -0.08823788
   0.0320038  -0.00023023  0.10030443  0.01394301 -0.07903008  0.03293093
   0.15368395 -0.11213656  0.07401505  0.06123362 -0.1783725  -0.0788461
   0.04645948 -0.00024172  0.03527135  0.02592313  0.11341458  0.07026253
  -0.0544541   0.09657887 -0.17342299  0.0612987  -0.07760912  0.00467722
  -0.10431045  0.03944225  0.10737552  0.07386835 -0.06278969 -0.04545485
  -0.06690471  0.12865026 -0.18798149 -0.01798184 -0.168064    0.05734041
  -0.07086241 -0.08988202 -0.01063311  0.02298436 -0.03099938  0.11156233
  -0.12110745 -0.09365971]] ()
```

What could be the possible solution?

Comment: The error says that these arrays contain large strings ('<U1580'), not numbers.  You can check that by looking at the `dtype`.  Your arrays have been 'serialized', converted to strings that can go through POST and sql.  They have to be converted back to numeric arrays to do math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that the value when retrieved from database was a string.

This was in ndarray

```
[[ 0.1616196... ]]
```

but the content in Inner Brackets was a string.

So after reshaping I was able to perform the desired operation.